# Undefined type 'Dotenv\Dotenv\Dotenv'

Tags: php, composer-php, phpdotenv

Is this the way to use a package installed from composer?

```
<?php

use Dotenv\Dotenv;

require_once __DIR__ . '/../../../vendor/autoload.php';

$dotenv = Dotenv\Dotenv::createImmutable(dirname(__DIR__, 3));
$dotenv->load();
```

From the [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cjO9i.png), it looks like it didn't recognize the Dotenv\Dotenv......

Comment: it's most likely `$dotenv = Dotenv::createIm...` since you're already using `use` to give an alias [Aliasing-Namespace](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php)

Comment: Just dump these command and use env(). Saved my time!

Comment: If there is any problem with the given code, please share it in readable form